# Disabling ligatures and text figures in Open Type Font

Tags: css, typography, opentype

I am using Raleway Webfont by Google for headings on our site but the Boss noticed the ligatures formed by 2 ffs and fi etc and also the text figures (numbers with ascenders and descenders) and thinks our biggest vendor might take issue with their name being written out with ligatures and text figures. I have tried turniong these off with the following CSS but with no luck.

http://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/WxQPYQ

CSS I have tried

```
h1 {font-family: Raleway; font-size: 4rem;

  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  font-feature-settings: unset;
  font-variant: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `letter-spacing` to `1px` to achieve what you are looking for.

**For instance, as per your code,**

```
h1 {font-family: Raleway; font-size: 4rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    font-feature-settings: unset;
    font-variant: normal;
    }
```

**[Live demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBvbYR)**

You can also check the **[Comparative demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/b2q7bezg/1/)**

For numeric figures, as mentioned by the OP, you can use `font-feature-settings` with the value `lnum` along with `font-variant-numeric` with the value `normal`.

**For instance,**

```
h1 {font-family: Raleway; font-size: 4rem; letter-spacing: 1px;

  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  font-feature-settings: unset;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-variant-numeric: normal;
  font-feature-settings: 'lnum';

}
```

**[Comparative Live demo - For numeric figures](https://jsfiddle.net/b2q7bezg/2/)**

You can read more about the same on the below W3 guidelines.

> **[W3 guidelines on *font-variant-numeric*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-fonts-20130212/#propdef-font-variant-numeric)**

Comment: Thanks Nathan L . I adjusted to 0.1px to prevent the extra kerning.

I just need to figure out the figure text now.

Comment: I would still suggest 1px, as 0.1 being a tricky value might not render on some browser versions.

Comment: I have found the solution for the numbers 
 font-feature-settings: 'lnum';

Comment: oh that's great .. Thanks for updating .. Make sure it is cross-browser compatible .. At-least with the latest ones